# Critical dependency: updating create-react-app from 1.1.5 to 2.18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Currently trying to update a create-react-app application from 1.1.5 to 2.1.8. Getting an error returned.

> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

For the following section of code.

```
// If browser doesn't support Intl (i.e. Safari), then we manually import
// the intl polyfill and locale data.
if (!window.intl) {
(require: any).ensure(
        ["intl", "intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js", "intl/locale-data/jsonp/zh.js"],
        require => {
            require("intl");
            require("intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js");
            require("intl/locale-data/jsonp/zh.js");
            render(renderApp, element);
    });
} else {
    // otherwise just render app normally
    render(renderApp, element);
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any idea why this code is a problem now that I have update my react-scripts from 1.1.5 to 2.1.8?

Have been looking through similar tickets but not having much success.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

UI

using node v11.9.0 and npm 6.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ending up removing the require code.
Working fine.

Comment: Issue was part of breaking changes in react 2.0.3 updates.

Code-splitting with import() now behaves closer to specification, while require.ensure() is disabled.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/01/create-react-app-v2.html